# UI component hidden input on checkout address

Tags: magento2

I am adding custom field on Magento 2 checkout shipping address.
It's a hidden input.
The value should be automatically updated based on another custom field which is a select (populated from ajax response data), using its option text/label.
How can I "link" between input value and selected option text?

In my current custom component for the select, it already export the value to input

```
            exports: {
            value: '${ $.provider }:shippingAddress.custom_attributes.subdstrict:value'
        }
```

But it sends the selected value instead of the text. how to send the selected option text instead?

Comment: Teja, did you find any solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this using this code

```
    return Select.extend({
    defaults: {
        skipValidation: false,
        exports: {
            // Don: any change to subdisrict_id dropdown will "send" notifcation to subdistrict input
            selectedSubdistrictName: '${ $.provider }:${ $.customScope }.custom_attributes.subdistrict:value'
        }
    },

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    initObservable: function () {
        this._super()
            .observe(['selectedSubdistrictName']);

        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Filters 'initialOptions' property by 'field' and 'value' passed,
     * calls 'setOptions' passing the result to it
     *
     * @param {*} value
     * @param {String} field
     */
    initialize : function(){
        var self = this;
        this._super();
        self.value.subscribe(function(value){
            self.selectedSubdistrictName( self.getPreview() );
        }, this)
    },

filter: function (value, field) {
        if(value) {
            var thisField = this;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/rest/V1/fabelio-directory/subdistricts/' + value,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    // rename keys
                    var options = [];
                    var option = {};
                    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        option = {
                            'value': data[i].subdistrict_id,
                            'label': data[i].name
                        };
                        options.push(option);

                    }
                    thisField.setOptions(options);
                },
                error: function() {
                },
                complete: function() {
                }
            });
        }

    }

});
});
```